# Getting all processes in desktop

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I have created a new desktop using CreateDesktop and would like to be able to enumerate all processes within that desktop.

I have tried this:

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    foreach (ProcessThread processThread in process.Threads)
    {
        IntPtr hDesk = GetThreadDesktop((uint)processThread.Id);
        if (hDesk == desk)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get Access is denied exception. I can also use

```
EnumDesktopWindows
```

However, this doesn't work for command line applications. (I am trying to prevent keyloggers)

Is there any way to get all processes within a desktop?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try CMD as Admin?

Comment: Yeah, and it still says access denied

Comment: Interesting. I am going to give this a try. So you want to create a desktop, then enum all windows on the created desktop, correct? What happens if you call `EnumDesktopWindows` with `IntPtr.Zero` as the first parameter?

Comment: Well I know how to do it with Windows, but what about console apps? That’s what I am trying to achieve

Comment: It works fine in console apps. Just did it. I will post my code in an answer.

Comment: @Andy Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: If you want to prevent from [hooking keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) input of the desktop. Since hook need a message loop to receive keyboard messages, which requires to create a window. So restrict other users to create window application associate to your desktop can prevent them from logging keyboard inputs.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Yup, I had just realized that. Thank you for assuring me though.

Answer (score 2):

I spent the last hour playing with this and I have it working fine from a console window. The code is messy, but you should be able to make your way through it:

```
class Program
{
    private static class Win32Native
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum CreateDesktopFlags : uint
        {
            DF_NONE = 0,
            DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK = 1
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum CreateWindowAccessMask : uint
        {
            DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x0001,
            DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x0002,
            DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x0004,
            DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x0008,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x0010,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x0020,
            DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x0040,
            DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x0080,
            DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100,
            DESKTOP_ALL_ACCESS = 0x01FF
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum CreateProcessFlags : uint
        {
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010,
            CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public int cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public int dwX;
            public int dwY;
            public int dwXSize;
            public int dwYSize;
            public int dwXCountChars;
            public int dwYCountChars;
            public int dwFillAttribute;
            public int dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetProcessWindowStation();

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public delegate bool EnumDesktopProc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumWindowsProc lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowTextW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClassNameW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CreateDesktopW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(
            string lpszDesktop, IntPtr lpszDevice,
            IntPtr pDevMode, CreateDesktopFlags dwFlags,
            CreateWindowAccessMask dwDesiredAccess,
            IntPtr lpsa);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopsW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool EnumDesktops(IntPtr hwinsta, EnumDesktopProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CloseDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CreateProcessW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CreateProcess(
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            CreateProcessFlags dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool TerminateProcess(IntPtr hProcess, uint uExitCode);
    }

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sbWndText = new StringBuilder(512),
            sbWndClass = new StringBuilder(512);

        Console.WriteLine("Trying current desktop:");
        if(!Win32Native.EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, (hWnd, lParam) =>
        {
            Win32Native.GetWindowText(hWnd, sbWndText, sbWndText.Capacity);
            Win32Native.GetClassName(hWnd, sbWndClass, sbWndClass.Capacity);

            Console.WriteLine($"Found Window: {hWnd} with title \"{sbWndText}\" and class name \"{sbWndClass}\"");

            return true;
        }, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine($"EnumDesktopWindows for current desktop failed with error {error}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Current desktops: ");
        Win32Native.EnumDesktops(Win32Native.GetProcessWindowStation(), (desktopName, lParam) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Found desktop: {desktopName}");
            return true;
        }, IntPtr.Zero);

        Console.WriteLine("Trying new desktop:");
        const string DesktopName = "ANDY DESKTOP NEATO 2";

        var hDesktop = Win32Native.CreateDesktop(
            DesktopName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
            Win32Native.CreateDesktopFlags.DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK,
            Win32Native.CreateWindowAccessMask.DESKTOP_ALL_ACCESS,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        if(hDesktop != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Win32Native.EnumDesktops(Win32Native.GetProcessWindowStation(), (desktopName, lParam) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found desktop: {desktopName}");
                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);

            var si = new Win32Native.STARTUPINFO();
            si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.lpDesktop = DesktopName;
            var pi = new Win32Native.PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            if(!Win32Native.CreateProcess(
                null, "cmd.exe", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false,
                Win32Native.CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE |
                    Win32Native.CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
                IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi))
            {
                var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Console.WriteLine($"Unable to create process on new desktop: {error}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("WAITING 2 SECONDS FOR PROCESS TO START...");
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // breath so the process starts

            if (!Win32Native.EnumDesktopWindows(hDesktop, (hWnd, lParam) =>
            {
                Win32Native.GetWindowText(hWnd, sbWndText, sbWndText.Capacity);
                Win32Native.GetClassName(hWnd, sbWndClass, sbWndClass.Capacity);

                Console.WriteLine($"Found Window: {hWnd} with title \"{sbWndText}\" and class name \"{sbWndClass}\"");

                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Console.WriteLine($"EnumDesktopWindows for new desktop failed with error {error}");
            }

            // IMPORTANT: close the processes you start, otherwise you desktop won't self-destruct.
            Win32Native.TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 42);
            Win32Native.CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            Win32Native.CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            Win32Native.CloseDesktop(hDesktop);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unable to create desktop: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

So the issue I think you were having with `EnumDesktopWindows` is that when you called `CreateDesktop`, you didn't ask for sufficient privileges. I set all privileges on (value of `0x1FF`) and then `EnumDesktopWindows` worked for me.

Keep in mind if you call `EnumDesktopWindows` and there are no windows to enumerate, it will return `false` with a value of `0` when you call `GetLastError`.

So what I did to prove that it actually is working is I created a process (`cmd.exe`) in the new desktop, then called `EnumDesktopWindows`.

Also keep in mind if you don't destroy all the processes in your new desktop, the desktop will not "self-destruct" and it will be alive until all the processes are destroyed or you logoff/reboot.

I also ran this as a normal user. I didn't need to elevate to administrator to make this work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220397/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-getting-all-processes-in-desktop).

Answer (score 0):

> However, this doesn't work for command line applications. (I am trying
> to prevent keyloggers)

Assume that you want to prevent from [hooking keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) input of the desktop.

Since hook need a message loop to receive keyboard messages, which requires to create a window. So **restrict other users to create window application associate to your desktop** can prevent them from logging keyboard inputs.

If you want to check the **desktop name** of a given process to see if it is same with your desktop's name (applied for window application) you can follow these steps:

1. Call [OpenProcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to get a `HANDLE` from the target process ID.
2. Call [NtQueryInformationProcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to retrieve the address of the process's `PEB` structure.
3. Call [ReadProcessMemory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to read the `PEB`. It's `ProcessParams.DesktopName` field contains the **name of the workstation/desktop** currently associated with the process (there are many more fields available in the [PEB.ProcessParams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-rtl_user_process_parameters?redirectedfrom=MSDN) then what MSDN shows).

Refer to "[How to get window station for a given process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144350/how-to-get-window-station-for-a-given-process)"